# prevent JOIN from matching same row over and over again

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have 2 tables like this

trans_data table

```
mnth| id | units
2   | ab | 20
3   | cd | 20
2   | ab | 25
2   | fd | 28
2   | ab | 40
2   | cd | 70
3   | ab | 80
2   | ab | 10
```

quota table

```
mnth | metric | id | quota
2    | 1      | ab | 30
2    | 1      | cd | 30
2    | 1      | fd | 30
3    | 1      | ab | 40
3    | 1      | cd | 40
3    | 1      | fd | 40
```

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT 
  SUM(trans_data.units) AS ga, SUM(quota.quota)
FROM
  trans_data 
  LEFT JOIN quota ON 
  trans_data.id = quota.id
  AND quota.mnth BETWEEN 2 AND 2 
  AND quota.metric = 1
WHERE trans_data.id = 'ab'    
  AND trans_data.mnth BETWEEN 2 AND 2
```

What is happening is that since there are multiple rows in the `trans_data` table that have a `id='ab'`, each of those rows is getting paired with the one row in quota that has `id='ab'`.

This throws off the sum value. what can i do so that the rows from quota are not repeated in the sum() calculation

*Desired Result:*

```
sum(trans_data.units)   |  sum(Quota.quota)
183                     | 30
```

Comment: you can use 'group by', and group result set by you primary key (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: You have multiple ids of ab but they units are different.  For id ab what unit do you want to use in the sum?  20, 25, 80 or others?

Comment: @Vulcronos sum(trans_units) should use all matching units so it would be equal to `183` and the sum(quota.quota) should equal `30`.

Comment: Please provide the results that you would like to get for the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the desired edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an INNER JOIN, just calculate the two sums independently:

```
SELECT ga, total_quota
FROM (SELECT SUM(units) AS ga
      FROM trans_data
      WHERE id = 'ab'
      AND mnth BETWEEN 2 AND 2) AS t1
CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(quota) AS total_quota
      FROM quota
      WHERE id = 'ab'
      AND mnth BETWEEN 2 AND 2
      AND metric = 1) AS t2
```

Or:

```
SELECT
     (SELECT SUM(units)
      FROM trans_data
      WHERE id = 'ab'
      AND mnth BETWEEN 2 AND 2) AS ga,
     (SELECT SUM(quota)
      FROM quota
      WHERE id = 'ab'
      AND mnth BETWEEN 2 AND 2
      AND metric = 1) AS total_quota
```

Comment: which one of the two is more efficient in your opinion?

Comment: I suspect they're equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to sum the quota in this case since there is only a singe row.  You could change the sum function to a max function in this case.  In general Barmar's solution is best since it will handle more than one row if that ever occurs.